# Changing href by value

Tags: html

i had a question about this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
var Opleidingen=[

[""],

["Try one", "try two"],

["1","2","3"]
];


function Box2(idx) {
var f=document.myform;
f.box2.options.length=null;
for(var i=0; i<Opleidingen[idx].length; i++) {
f.box2.options[i]=new Option(Opleidingen[idx][i], i); 
}    
}


window.onload=function() {
var box1=document.myform.box1;
box1.onchange=function(){Box2(this.selectedIndex);};
// create 2nd select
try { // IE
  var sel=document.createElement("<select name=\"box2\"><\/select>");
  }
catch(e) {
  var sel=document.createElement("select");
  sel.name = "box2";
  }

    document.myform.getElementsByTagName('fieldset')[0].insertBefore(sel,   
                             box1.nextSibling);
// fill 2nd select
Box2(0);
}
// ]]></script>

&nbsp;

<form action="(??????????????????????)" method="post" name="myform">
<fieldset><legend></legend><select name="box1">
<option disabled="" selected="">- Test -</option>           
           <optgroup label="Choose value test">
                                <optgroup label="A">
<option value="1">Value list 1 (1)</option>
<option value="5">Value list 2 (2)</option>  
<option value="6">Value list 3 (3)</option>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
start</option>      

</select>
<button type="submit">Zoeken</button></fieldset>
    </form>&nbsp;
```

I try to make this a dependent drop down list with every value from the second list to match with a link. For example:

(List 1) Value list 1 - (List 2) try one  - link: google.nl
(List 1) Value list 2 - (List 2) 2 - link: yahoo.nl

All on the same button at the end. I just started coding, so i would really appreciate the help! And where to put in the code

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How to insert different links to different values in list 2. all in 1 submit button. Like in the example: List 1) Value list 1 - (List 2) try one - link: google.nl (List 1) Value list 2 - (List 2) 2 - link: yahoo.nl                                                                Try the code in here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_default