# EXCEL dependent dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to make a dependent dropdown list with excel or with html.

I got the following problem with html: [Changing href by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33613678/changing-href-by-value)

But my problem with excel is when i have made the dependent drop down list, i try to get it to html but it just shows a table of content listed. Not a dependent dropdown list.

I mean by this thats you can't select values from a list, but it just shows a table of everything you put in to it. Does someone have any information about converting dependent dropdown lists to code?

I can't find anything on the internet..

Or does someone have knowledge about dependent dropdown lists? I would really like to hear from you!